# How can I non-recursively migrate directories with Perl or shell?

Tags: perl, shell, directory

We're migrating home folders to a new filesystem, and I am looking for a way to automate it using Perl or a shell script. I don't have much choice in programming languages as the systems are proprietary storage clusters that should remain as unchanged as possible.

Task: Under directory /home/ I have various users' home folders aaa, bbb, ccc, ... and they have certain permissions and user/group ownership that need to remain intact upon migration to /newhome/. Here's example of what needs to be migrated from /home:

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 aaaaa    xxxxxxxxx   4096 Feb 26  2008 aaaaa/
drwxrwxrwx   88 bbbbbbb  yyyyyy      8192 Dec 16 16:32 bbbbbbb/
drwxr-xr-x    6 ccccc    yyyyyy      4096 Nov 24 04:38 ccccc/
drwxr-xrwx   36 dddddd   yyyyyy      4096 Jun 20  2008 dddddd/
drwxr-xr-x   27 eee      yyyyyy      4096 Dec 16 02:56 eee/
```

So, exact same folders with permissions and ownerships should be created under /newhome. Copying/moving files should not be a concern, as it will be handled later.

Anyone has worked on such script? I am really new to Perl, so I need help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cp`'s -a flag will maintain permission, modification times etc. You should for be able to do something like:

```
for a in `ls /home`; do cp -a "/home/$a" "/newhome/$a" ; done
```

Try it with one directory to see if does what you need before automating it.

EDIT: You can disable recursive file copying by using rsync or tar as mentioned by Paul. With rsync, subdirectories are still preserved, but files aren't copied:

```
sudo rsync -pgodt /home/ /newhome/
```

I haven't tried tar's --no-recursion, so can't comment on it.

EDIT 2: Another way

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 1 -print | sudo cpio -pamVd /newhome
```

[Reference](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/cpio_directory.php)

Comment: Great 1-liner, thanks! Is there a way to tell cp not to copy sub-folders and files of each user directory? In other words, create just the top user directories under /home without copying content.

Comment: @DV: The man page states cp -a is equivalent to cp -dpr ... since the -r handles recursion, cp -dp should do what you want without recursion.

Comment: Adam, cp omits directories if -r is not specified, so -dp would only apply to files AFAIK.

Comment: codelogic is right, I can't get it to work as 'cp -dp' :( It seems that there's no way to have cp only copy the top folders below /home without copying all of their contents... :/

Comment: @codelogic:  Gotcha, I didn't realize DV wanted to create the top-level directories and leave them empty.  My bad.

Comment: Holy crap, the power of knowing the right commands. Big thanks, codelogic! Your last edit works perfectly!

Comment: `-print` is unnecessary so it could be dropped or better yet replaced by `-print0`.

Comment: So my first part of the command is:
"find /home -maxdepth 1 -type d"
and then I pipe the output to cpio.

Answer (score 4):

You can only preserve the owner and group if you do the copying operation as `root`.  Most of the commands given will work - the `tar` and the `cp -rp` options will.

The only trick to worry about is non-writable directories, but that's an issue for non-root users.  Then, I tend to use:

```
(cd /home; find . -depth) | cpio -pvdumB /newhome
```

The `-depth` option means that file and sub-directories are processed before the directories themselves, so the no-write permission on the directory is only set after all the contents of the directory have been copied into it.  You can also use a '`sort -r`' to list files in reverse order, which ensures that directories appear after their contents.

Answer (score 3):

This will create the directories *and* copy all the files.

```
cd /home; tar cvBf - . | (cd /newhome; tar xvpBf -)
```

If you don't want to copy all the files, you might be able to do that by adding a "--no-recursion" to the first tar command.

Comment: I'll try that. I'm looking for no recursion, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't copy permissions/ownership when I tried it. Maybe I wasn't doing something right.

Comment: @DV: add `sudo` before `tar`.

Comment: @DV - or do it as root.  Make sure you include that "p" in the second tar, that copies the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If these directories are on the same filesystem, why not simply

```
cp -p /home/* /newhome/
```

Comment: I'll try that - I can mount the /newhome/ through the NFS. Thanks!

Comment: That does it, but there's still recursion (i.e. it copies all sub-directories and files as well). Is there a way to tell cp not do recursion?